# При уменьшении или увеличении размера окна браузера некорректное отображается

Tags: css3, html5

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.maket {
  background-image: url(http://vestamir.ru/d/770134/d/01-09-025.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {}

.button_back {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #000;
  letter-spacing: 1.6px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: #000;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  padding-left: 23px;
  padding-right: 23px;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
  margin-left: 85%;
  margin-top: 41%;
}
```

```html
<div class="maket">
  <div class="conteiner">
    <a href="Главная.html" class="button_back">&larr;Вернуться на главную</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: я просто не смог добавить картинки там если посмотреть добавляются отступы которые не очень выглядят

Comment: `некорректное отображается` - что именно? Вопрос надо формулировать так, что не приходилось заумные вопросы задавать...  Добавь в  вопрос конкретики..

Comment: некорректное  отображается текст он то больше картинки то очень маленький и не там стоит

Answer (score 0):

Ну почему же не корректно? Всё корректно согласно вашим стилям.
Уберите у кнопки `margin-left` или установите `auto` и задайте нужный `margin-right`

Comment: Это больше похож на комментарий, чем на ответ...

Comment: @Air как раз это решение. Удивляют программисты, которые вместо тестов того, что посоветовали, начинают рассуждать на тему "На что это похоже"